# Join the same table thrice and retrieve a column from those

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ,PH.PHONE_TYPE_CD
  ,PH.PHONE_NUM
FROM PERSON P
LEFT JOIN PHONE PH
   ON PH.PARENT_ENTITY_ID         = P.PERSON_ID
  AND PH.PARENT_ENTITY_NAME       = 'PERSON'
  AND PH.PHONE_TYPE_CD            = ?
  AND PH.ACTIVE_IND               = 1
LEFT JOIN PHONE PH
   ON PH.PARENT_ENTITY_ID         = P.PERSON_ID
  AND PH.PARENT_ENTITY_NAME       = 'PERSON'
  AND PH.PHONE_TYPE_CD            = ?
  AND PH.ACTIVE_IND               = 1
LEFT JOIN PHONE PH
   ON PH.PARENT_ENTITY_ID         = P.PERSON_ID
  AND PH.PARENT_ENTITY_NAME       = 'PERSON'
  AND PH.PHONE_TYPE_CD            = ?
  AND PH.ACTIVE_IND               = 1
```

Here `PHONE_TYPE_CD` will be passed from the Java side and based on the `PHONE_TYPE_CD`, the query should run and return results.

Since I am new to SQL, I am not sure how to achieve this. I understand all the 3 joins should have aliases like `PHONE PH1, PHONE PH2` and so on.. My question is can I code like below and get the `PHONE_NUM` based on the passed `PHONE_TYPE_CD`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ,PH1.PHONE_TYPE_CD
  ,PH1.PHONE_NUM
  ,PH2.PHONE_TYPE_CD
  ,PH2.PHONE_NUM
  ,PH3.PHONE_TYPE_CD
  ,PH3.PHONE_NUM
  FROM PERSON P
LEFT JOIN PHONE PH1
   ON PH1.PARENT_ENTITY_ID         = P.PERSON_ID
  AND PH1.PARENT_ENTITY_NAME       = 'PERSON'
  AND PH1.PHONE_TYPE_CD            = ?
  AND PH1.ACTIVE_IND               = 1
LEFT JOIN PHONE PH2
   ON PH2.PARENT_ENTITY_ID         = P.PERSON_ID
  AND PH2.PARENT_ENTITY_NAME       = 'PERSON'
  AND PH2.PHONE_TYPE_CD            = ?
  AND PH2.ACTIVE_IND               = 1
LEFT JOIN PHONE PH3
   ON PH3.PARENT_ENTITY_ID         = P.PERSON_ID
  AND PH3.PARENT_ENTITY_NAME       = 'PERSON'
  AND PH3.PHONE_TYPE_CD            = ?
  AND PH.ACTIVE_IND                = 1
```

I have ambiguity regarding the retrieval part.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: PHONE_TYPE_CD contains data like HOME, BUSINESS, OFFICE. So when the PHONE_TYPE_CD is HOME, I want to retrieve the PHONE_NUM of that type

Comment: Try to give us a sample Data Structure so we can give you an answer to your question not just simply stating your condition.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get it,what kind of Data Structure you are expecting?

Comment: Like when you run your script what expected output you want to get. The result table.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ,PH1.PHONE_TYPE_CD
  ,PH1.PHONE_NUM
  ,PH2.PHONE_TYPE_CD
  ,PH2.PHONE_NUM
  ,PH3.PHONE_TYPE_CD
  ,PH3.PHONE_NUM
  FROM PERSON P
LEFT JOIN PHONE PH1
   ON PH1.PARENT_ENTITY_ID         = P.PERSON_ID
  AND PH1.PARENT_ENTITY_NAME       = 'PERSON'
  AND PH1.PHONE_TYPE_CD            in (type1, type2, type3)
  AND PH1.ACTIVE_IND               = 1
```